# What's an efficient way to calculate the hash code of a C Union?

Tags: c, hash, hashmap, hashtable

For the given C UNION below, what would be an efficient way to calculate a hash code for it? Should I use the raw binary data in memory? Or should I try to interpret the contents of the UNION to calculate the hash code?

```
#ifdef AF_INET6

#define SOCKADDR        union { \
                            struct sockaddr_in him4; \
                            struct sockaddr_in6 him6; \
                        }

#define SOCKADDR_LEN    (ipv6_available() ? sizeof(SOCKADDR) : \
                         sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))

#else

#define SOCKADDR        union { struct sockaddr_in him4; }
#define SOCKADDR_LEN    sizeof(SOCKADDR)

#endif
```

---

I have tried to cast it to `(struct sockaddr_in *)` and use the `sa_in->sin_addr.s_addr` and `sa_in->sin_port`. But that does not feel right. I'm ignoring `struct sockaddr_in6` completely. Should I just use the raw memory data? How?

---

```
struct sockaddr_in6 {
               sa_family_t     sin6_family;   /* AF_INET6 */
               in_port_t       sin6_port;     /* port number */
               uint32_t        sin6_flowinfo; /* IPv6 flow information */
               struct in6_addr sin6_addr;     /* IPv6 address */
               uint32_t        sin6_scope_id; /* Scope ID (new in 2.4) */
           };

           struct in6_addr {
               unsigned char   s6_addr[16];   /* IPv6 address */
           };

struct sockaddr_in{  
    short sin_family;  
    unsigned short sin_port;  
struct in_addr sin_addr;  
    char sin_zero[8];  
};
```

Comment: Actual solutions in C++ and C will be different, and unions don't have nearly the same semantics between the two. So pick *one* language you are actually working with.

Comment: The size of the data in that first `union` will be difrerent depending on the property you're dealing with. You can't hash it without knowing the actual size involved. `sizeof(SOCKADDR)` gives you the maximum size, not the size of what's actually stored in it.

Comment: *"People from C++ might know that too..."* A C++ answer would probably start with "Don't use a union".

Answer (score 2):

You must interpret the actual content of the union, at least in general. The simple reason is that parts might be unused, i.e. not contribute to the effective value of the union. For example, a struct may have padding between members to align members. For a union, you can easily have padding at the end, when different union members have different sizes. If you ignore this, unions that are equal for all practical purposes will have different hash values.

Comment: Is it correct to just cast my SOCKADDR to (struct sockaddr_in *) and get the ip and port for hashing?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. For IP v4, the port should be a 16-bit number and the IP address a 32-bit number or four 8-bit numbers.

Comment: But what happens if it is not IPv4? There's also a `struct sockaddr_in6`. That's scaring me. Can I just cast fearlessly?

Comment: @LatencyFighter: You must hash only the fields that are relevant to the value currently stored in the union.  Any padding within the current value has indeterminate values; any padding beyond the end of the current value has indeterminate values.  Neither makes for good hashing material.  I'm not convinced there's any type you can cast to that is unambiguously safe.  You need a discriminated union, and the hash needs to be sensitive to the currently stored value.

Comment: Well, you must check the `sa_family_type` field to assert that it's IP v4. And, if it isn't, your code should either fail loudly or handle the case accordingly.

Comment: So my UNION will have either a `sockaddr_in` or a `sockaddr_in6`. How do I check which one I have there, so I can cast to the right type?

Comment: See above, I just wrote how to.

Comment: Do you mind showing through code how I would do that? I will definitely mark your answer as the best. I don't see `sa_family_type` anywhere in the type declarion, I'm confused. Thanks!